# Trouble displaying transaction ID in WSO2 logs using log4j MDC – limited to a single bundle

Tags: wso2, log4j, osgi, mdc

I am attempting to pass a transaction ID to WSO2 and display it in the logs using log4j MDC. However, I am encountering an issue where the transaction ID is only displayed in a single bundle, whereas I expect it to be present in logs across all bundles.

.Here is how I am injecting the transaction ID into the log4j MDC context in my code:

`

```
        <script language="js"><![CDATA[

           importPackage(Packages.java.net);
           importPackage(Packages.org.apache.log4j);
           var transactionId = String(mc.getProperty('transactionId'))
           try {
             
                MDC.put("transactionId", transactionId);
               
           } catch (e) {
            print( "======> " +e )
           }
       ]]></script>`
```

Is there something I might be missing in my configuration that could explain why the transaction ID is not being propagated correctly across all bundles?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdyAu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsKir.jpg)